# Back button update list

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Currently I am creating a chat application. When launching the application an api call is made to pull at the information. In that call a for loop is created to create objects out of the JSON array that is being received from the API. From there a call is made to a handler that will set the adapter and layout manager.

Below is what it looks like: (NOTICE it shows the last message in the thread)

[image]

When you click on one of the lists it opens up a chat like so.

[image]

When I type a message and click send then press the back button to go back to my list of messages. It shows the same screen as before (No update of the last message sent). When the app is restarted it pulls from the API and the last message is seen.

Basically how to I rebuild the fragment or call the API again upon pressing the back button?

Fragment:

```
public class conversationsFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView usersListView;

ArrayList<MessageData> arrMessageData; //= new ArrayList<MessageData>();

conversationRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;
Bitmap image;


public conversationsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_conversations, container, false);

    usersListView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.conversationsListView);


    new Load().execute(null, null, null);




    return rootView;

}


class Load extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog pd;

    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {




        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new BasicAuthInterceptor()).addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor()).build();

        String credentials = "ezhu:Ccare@123";
        String auth = "Basic "
                + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

        Log.e("Test", auth);




        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String auth_token_string = settings.getString("token", ""/*default value*/);
        String auth_token_type = settings.getString("tokenType", "");
        String userId = settings.getString("userId", "");

        Log.i("prefs", auth_token_type);



        String url  = "https://staging.vitalengine.com/portal-api/api/user/inbox/list?userId=" +
                userId +
                "&folderId=-1&tagId=0&page=1&itemPerPage=1000&showMsgInFolder=false";


        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url)
                .addHeader("Authorization", auth_token_type + " " + auth_token_string)
                .addHeader("user-tz", "-330")
                        //.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();




        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                // Log.i(TAG, "call api error");
                Log.e("Volley", e.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response)  {

                try {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful())
                        throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                    final String body = response.body().string();


                    JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(body);



                    JSONObject sub = Jobject.getJSONObject("response");
                    JSONArray Jarray = sub.getJSONArray("inboxMsgList");



                    arrMessageData = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        if (object.get("messageType").equals("CONVERSATION")) {



                            Log.e("ConversationTest", object.getString("fromUser"));

                            MessageData msg3 = new MessageData();
                            msg3.setName((String) object.get("fromUser"));
                            msg3.setMessage((String) object.get("message"));
                            getImage((String) object.get("photo"));
                            msg3.setImage(image);
                            msg3.setRead(true);
                            msg3.setSubject((String) object.get("subject"));
                            msg3.setType((String) object.get("conversationDate"));
                            msg3.setId((Integer) object.get("conversationId"));

                            arrMessageData.add(msg3);
                        } else {

                        }




                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);

                    }



                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }


        });
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pd.setMessage("loading");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pd != null)
        {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }
}


private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case 1:
                adapter = new conversationRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), arrMessageData);
                usersListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                        = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                usersListView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                break;
            default:
                Log.d("TAG", msg.what + " ? ");
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You simply override onBackPressed(). Then you can do whatever updating you need in that method.

Comment: I tried that, and it says method onBackPressed is unused. Does it matter that this is a fragment? Also get an error when I run. Error:(67, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Comment: You override the onBackPressed in the Activity that's calling the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() {
          if(adapter!=null)       
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

Comment: I tried that, and it says method onBackPressed is unused. Does it matter that this is a fragment? Also get an error when I run. Error:(67, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Comment: Implement it inside your activity